Implement the index(after:) method to be displayed in reverse order
I'm studying the Collection protocol and decided to implement my own collection, but I didn't stop there and wanted to implement the index(after:) method so that it works the other way around
struct SimpleCollection: Collection {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    var startIndex: Int { numbers.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { numbers.endIndex }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return numbers[index]
    }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return numbers.index(after: i)
    }
}

Here is my structure and I want to implement the Index(after:) method so that it is output in the opposite direction
let test = SimpleCollection();
for items in test{
    print(items)
}

What is being displayed now
1
2
3
4
5

What i want
5
4
3
2
1


For this to work, you not only has to implement index(after:) correctly, but also startIndex, endIndex, and the subscript. Your current implementation of these do not create a reversed collection - test[test.startIndex] should return 5, but it returns 1 instead.
A simple idea is to have your collection's startIndex be the array's endIndex, and the same applies to endIndex.
var startIndex: Int { numbers.endIndex }
var endIndex: Int { numbers.startIndex }

Now we run into another problem. test[numbers.startIndex] crashes, because numbers.endIndex is not a valid index for numbers. We need to change the implementation of the subscript to use the index before.
subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers[numbers.index(before: index)] // or just numbers[index - 1]
}

Finally, we implement index(after:), which is straightforward. Just return the index before the given index.
func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.index(before: i) // or just i - 1
}

Note that you are basically reinventing ReversedCollection (the type returned by the reversed method). Check out its implementation for how to do this in the general case, where the underlying collection can be any BidirectionalCollection.
The main idea is the same as what I have shown above, but notably, the built-in ReversedCollection uses a custom Index type, instead of using the same Index as the underlying collection. This clearly differentiates between indices of the reversed collection, vs the indices of the original collection, which are semantically very different.

I did it like this
struct SimpleCollection: Collection {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    var startIndex: Int { numbers.endIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { numbers.startIndex }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return numbers.index(before: index)
    }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return  numbers.index(before: i)
    }
}

And it is output
4
3
2
1
0

But i want
5
4
3
2
1


@koshe1ca The subscript is incorrect. Read my answer again.
